# Handling protocol activation of Uri that throws a UriFormatException

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I'making an app, which consists of a webview that shows a website. The website will navigate to a protocol (using javascript's `window.location = ...`). I'm trying to hook into that protocol, so I can parse the data that the app is sending to me. The problem is that the website uses this protocol:

```
scheme://key1=value&key2=value&key3=value...
```

This is not a valid Uri according to System.Uri:

```
System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
```

I cannot change the website, so I'm stuck with this invalid format. I've tried using the UnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified event, but since I'm only able to get an Uri object from that, it instantly crashes when I try to access the Uri.

I've also tried declaring a protocol, and handling the event in the App.OnActivated method. But once again, I can only access the Uri, which instantly crashes the application.

After that, I tried using Reflection to directly pull the string from the `WebViewUnsupportedUriSchemeIdentifiedEventArgs`, but I couldn't find any private fields.

**Edit:** I've also tried loading the page using HttpClient, and then replacing the invalid uri with a valid one, but this breaks the rest of the site because the JS depends on window.location, which isn't set properly when using `webView.NavigateToString(...)`

So how do I get access to the Uri data? I can't change the website, but I can inject JavaScript via the WebView if absolutely neseccary.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly? Some code on the page loaded into WebView attempts to *navigate* to that incorrect URI. As it is also not supported by WebView the UnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified event is fired. What exactly are you trying to fix?

Comment: I can't understand your question, what are you doing? You want to navigate to a website (which you can't change) with your own defined scheme of Uri? Or combine your scheme and the uri of this website together? There is uri parsing method of [Uri class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.uri.aspx), but I'm not sure it can solve your problem, and here are legal [URI schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx) in UWP app.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I'm making an app, and I need to load a website in a webview (can't change the website). The website will communicate with the app by nagivating to the scheme/protocol I described in my question. My app then needs to extract some data from the Uri, but because the Uri is not a valid format, this isn't working. I'll edit my question to explain this more clearly.

Comment: If you can't change the website, what you mean by communicating with the app? Like login the web? Do you have dev doc of this website?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT The website uses the protocol to tell the app to, for example, show a certain dialog or change the text in the title bar. The website will do that by, for example, navigating to scheme://method=setTitle&title=New_Title

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in protocol format. Here is basically the format you should use:

```
scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]
```

In your case you are omitting host part. If it is empty, you can keep it empty -- in that case your URI will have tripled slash:

```
scheme:///key1=value&key2=value&key3=value...
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the website itself, meaning that I'm stuck with the invalid protocol. I'm looking for some way around the Uri parsing to at least get the data that's in the Uri.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't solved it yet, here is my solution.
First change html in webview.

```
window.location = direct('scheme://key1=value&key2=value&key3=value...');
```

use like that and in that function send that link to a website like url shortner and get a short url and now you will get a uri in WebViewUnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified event.

you can use something like that

```
 Cache.Insert("1234", TextBox1.Text, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30), TimeSpan.Zero);

Cache.Get("1234").ToString();
```

Comment: sorry for bad expression :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the content in the webview.